# MSSQL JOIN ON GROUP BY is too slow

Tags: sql-server, database, optimization, join, subquery

I have the following query in MSSQL

```
SELECT TOP 50 CustomerID FROM Ratings
WHERE CustomerID != 915
AND MovieID IN (SELECT DISTINCT MovieID FROM Ratings WHERE CustomerID = 915)
GROUP BY CustomerID
ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

It is super fast. When I try to use it in a subquery like this.

```
SELECT * FROM Ratings
WHERE MovieID = 1 AND
CustomerID IN (SELECT TOP 50 CustomerID FROM Ratings
    WHERE CustomerID != 915
    AND MovieID IN (SELECT DISTINCT MovieID FROM Ratings WHERE CustomerID = 915)
    GROUP BY CustomerID
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC)
```

Any ideas on why this is so slow and how I can speed it up? My primary key is (MovieID-CustomerID) and I added a index on CustomerID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to create an extra `UNIQUE` index on `(CustomerID, MovieID)` (in this order) to improve this query.

See the article in my blog for performance details:

- [**Rating movies**](http://explainextended.com/2009/04/30/rating-movies/)

Since your subqueries return `UNIQUE` sets of values, the query may be rewritten as a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT  r2.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  TOP 50 CustomerID
        FROM    (
                SELECT  MovieID
                FROM    Ratings
                WHERE   CustomerID = 915
                ) q
        JOIN    Ratings r
        ON      r.MovieID = q.MovieID
                AND CustomerID <> 915
        GROUP BY
                CustomerID
        ORDER BY
                COUNT(*) DESC
        ) ro
JOIN    Ratings r2
ON      r2.MovieID = 1
        AND r2.CustomerID = ro.CustomerID
```

To select `TOP 50` customers of those who have rated `Movie 1`, use:

```
SELECT  r2.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  TOP 50 CustomerID
        FROM    (
                SELECT  MovieID
                FROM    Ratings
                WHERE   CustomerID = 915
                ) q
        JOIN    Ratings r
        ON      r.MovieID = q.MovieID
                AND CustomerID <> 915
                AND EXISTS
                (
                SELECT  1
                FROM    Ratings re
                WHERE   re.MovieID = 1
                        AND re.CustomerID = r.CustomerID
                )
        GROUP BY
                CustomerID
        ORDER BY
                COUNT(*) DESC
        ) ro
JOIN    Ratings r2
ON      r2.MovieID = 1
        AND r2.CustomerID = ro.CustomerID
```

Comment: Awesome! Only thing is it sometimes returns slightly less than 50, probably cause some of the top people haven't rated MovieID 1. But I should be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: Sweet I got my thing fully working. BTW the query analyzer suggested the same index as you and it helped a lot.